# Angular UI Grid Rendering, but Options Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm able to get the grid to render and it contains the data that is passed into it from gridOptions, however, none of the custom options I've set are taking effect on the grid. It appears to be behaving in a completely default manner.

What do I need to change in order to have my custom options take effect on the grid?

Here is example code showing the problem, as well as a Plunker showing it in action:

http://plnkr.co/edit/OAguQzkn19RGvFg2FUTF?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.gridOptions = {
      enableCellSelection: true,
      enableColumnResize: true,
      enableColumnReordering: true,
      enablePinning: true,
      enableRowReordering: true,
      enableRowSelection: true,
      enableSorting: true,

      data: [
        {
          "firstName": "Cox",
          "lastName": "Carney",
          "company": "Enormo",
          "employed": true
        },
        {
          "firstName": "Lorraine",
          "lastName": "Wise",
          "company": "Comveyer",
          "employed": false
        },
        {
          "firstName": "Nancy",
          "lastName": "Waters",
          "company": "Fuelton",
          "employed": false
        }
      ]
    };
}]);

</script>
```

Comment: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/099_upgrading_from_2 "Many elements included by default in ng-grid have now been shifted into separate features, allowing the core ng-grid to be kept smaller and faster. Features are enabled only when included, inclusion of a feature requires both including the module in your application and adding the feature directive onto the grid definition."  "Features include:
•column resizing
•selection
•cell navigation and selection of individual cells
•editing in place"

Comment: basically, you can't just use the 2.x way of declaring the features in the `gridOptions`, you now need to include the feature and add the specific directive to the `<div>`.